# Datarow object, why is this code working?

Tags: sql, asp.net, c#-4.0

after assign a row values of datatabe to a new data row object , any changes in this object affects on the data table , Why ?

have a look at this code.

```
  DataRow dr = mydataset.Tables["NewTable"].Rows[0];
  dr["Name"] = "hello";
```

Now if you try to debug your application you will find that the original data table ["NewTable"] has the new value hello instead of the old value Although we didn't return back the above data row to data table (we didn't save it )

I Just need a clarification and also need to know & understand  what actually happen when i create an Object of a data row .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both DataTable and DataRow are reference data types. This means that when you assign a variable to its reference in code, it simply holds a pointer back to the same memory location.

```
DataRow dr1 = mydataset.Tables["NewTable"].Rows[0];
DataRow dr2 = mydataset.Tables["NewTable"].Rows[0];
DataRow dr3 = dr1;
DataTable dt = mydataset.Tables["NewTable"];
DataRow dr4 = dt.Rows[0];
```

In the above example, dr1, dr2, dr3, and dr4 all point to the same memory location. Therefore if you edit dr4, the changes will appear on dr1, dr2, and dr3.

See [Value Types and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) for more information.